# Prove that $\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n,\underline{u}\right\}=\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, span

Suppose that $\underline{u},\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n\in\mathbb{R^n}$

$\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n,\underline{u}\right\}=\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n\right\}$ iff $\underline{u}$ is a linear combinations of others.

My suggested proof:

Let $\bf{v}\in$ $\underline{u},\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n$

So there are scalars $c_1,...c_n$ such that

$\bf{v}$$=c_1\underline{w}_1+...+c_n\underline{w}_n+0\underline{u}=c_1\underline{w}_1+...+c_n\underline{w}_n$

So $\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n,\underline{u}\right\}=\text{span}\left\{\underline{w}_1,...,\underline{w}_n\right\}$?

I'm not sure if the proof is correct.

Comment: If you are saying that $v$ belongs to the span of those vectors, then why is zero the coefficient of $u$? Since the spans are equal, there exist scalars $s,c_i,d_i$ such that $$v = s\cdot u + c_1\cdot w_1+\cdots+c_n\cdot w_n$$ $$= k_1\cdot w_1+\cdots+k_n\cdot w_n$$

Comment: I just assumed $u$ is the same as $w_{n+1}$. Could you explain your proof further? Where did you get $k$ from?

Comment: Short advice, to make it clearer for you what you need to demonstrate at each step, separate your proof of $A=B$ in $A \subset B$ and then $B \subset A$. Or in this case separate $P \text{ iff } Q$ into $P \implies Q$ and $Q \implies P$.

Comment: sorry, i changed my notation without fixing it. the $k_i$'s should have been $d_i$'s. My point was to write $v$ as a linear combination in both of the sets separately, and then use the fact that they are equal to show $u$ is a linear combination of the $w$'s

Comment: I misunderstood the proposition. I thought that Span$\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ will be $\mathbb{R}^n$. I deleted immediately as soon as I noticed my mistake :). Thanks for warnings @Alex H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V=$ Span$\{u,w_1,\ldots,w_n\}=$ Span$\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ then for any $v\in V$ there exists $s,c_i,d_i$ such that
\begin{align}
v &=su+c_1w_1+\cdots+c_nw_n\\
  &=d_1w_1+\ldots+d_nw_n.
\end{align}
We can accept without loss of generality $s\neq 0$ so $u=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{s}(d_i-c_i)w_i$. Other implication is obvious so we are done.

**EDIT** $\frac{1}{s}$ added to the expression of $u$. Since Span$\{u,w_1,\ldots,w_n\}=$ Span$\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$, the set $\{u,w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is linearly dependent so the expansion of $v$ is not unique in terms of $\{u,w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$. When $s=0$, the $c_i$'s must be $d_i$ and when $s\neq 0$ there are different $c_i$ and $d_i$.

Actually I noticed shortest proof of the proposition while typing the edit. If $V=$ Span$\{u,w_1,\ldots,w_n\}=$ Span$\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ then $u\in V=$ Span$\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$. Thus $u$ is a linear combination of $w_1,\ldots,w_n$

Answer (score 0):

No, the proof is incorrect.

Saying that $v\in\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n,u\}$ means you can write
$$
v=\alpha_1w_1+\dots+\alpha_nw_n+\beta u
$$
and there's no reason why $\beta$ should be $0$.

#### Trace of a proof.

First of all, show that
$$
\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}\subseteq
\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n,u\}
$$

Thus equality is the same as the reverse inclusion.

Now, suppose
$$
\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}\supseteq
\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n,u\}
$$
Then $u\in\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$, so…

Conversely, suppose $u=\gamma_1w_1+\dots+\gamma_nw_n$ and consider $v\in\operatorname{span}\{w_1,\dots,w_n,u\}$. Then you can write
$$
v=\alpha_1w_1+\dots+\alpha_nw_n+\beta u
=\alpha_1w_1+\dots+\alpha_nw_n+\beta(\gamma_1w_1+\dots+\gamma_nw_n)
$$
so…

Answer (score 0):

$$span\{w_1,...,w_n,u\}=span\{w_1,...,w_n\} \iff u = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iw_i$$

($\implies$)

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iw_i+\beta u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\gamma_iw_i$$
$$\beta u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\gamma_iw_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iw_i$$
$$\beta u=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\gamma_i-\alpha_i)w_i$$

($\impliedby$)

$$u = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iw_i \rightarrow u \in span\{w_1,...,w_n\}$$